# SharePoint REST API getFolderByServerRelativeUrl Returns Nothing

Tags: api, rest, sharepoint, endpoints

I would like to drill into the library and then into a specified folder, but I am having problems getting 'getFolderByServerRelativeUrl' to grab anything for me.

This `http://_base/_api/web/getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('LibName')/files` returns zero results. But if I use `http://_base/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('LibName')/items` it returns multiple items.

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but have you tried using a `/` before the library name when trying to access by server**relative**url?

Comment: I have but that doesn't get anything either. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<list title>')/items` endpoint returns **all** list items within a library,  `/_api/web/getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('<url>')/files` returns only files located under (*one level beneath only*) the specified folder.

**Example**

Assume the following Documents library structure:

```
Documents (library)
   |
   Guides (folder)
     |
     SharePoint User Guide.docx (file)
```

Then, the following request:

`/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items` will return 2 items:

- list item associated with `Guides` folder
- list item associated with file

At the same time, the request: `/_api/web/getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Documents')/files`

will returns `0` files since there are no files contained in the root folder

but the request with provided folder url:
`/_api/web/getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Documents/Guides')/files`

will return `SharePoint User Guide.docx` file.

Comment: how can i get just folders from my asset library

Answer (score -1):

You're using the wrong URL. Try appending it to the other URL.