# REST APi to get all times in specific folder in SharePoint document library

Tags: rest, sharepoint, office365api, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I would like to  get items in specific folder inside SharePoint document library called "Pages" with REST API

I used below rest API which I can get all items in document library
https://spsite/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Pages')/items

But I have not found the REST api which I can get all times in specific folder  inside SharePoint document library

Comment: What do you mean by "get all times", can you elaborate?

Comment: get all items under the specific folder in the document libarray, for example I have document library called "Pages" under this library I have folder called "Test" I want to get all items under "Test" folder

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are at least two options available to return items from a specific folder:

1) Using `/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('<serverrelativefolderurl>')` endpoint

The following example returns all the files along with associated list items from a specific folder:

```
/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('<serverrelativefolderurl>')/files?$expand=ListItemAllFields
```

2) using [`FolderServerRelativeUrl` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.camlquery.folderserverrelativeurl.aspx) of CAML query

```
function getListItems(webUrl,listTitle, queryText,folderUrl) 
{
    var viewXml = '<View><Query>' + queryText + '</Query></View>';
    var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/getitems"; 
    var queryPayload = {  
               'query' : {
                      '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' }, 
                      'ViewXml' : viewXml,
                      "FolderServerRelativeUrl": folderUrl 
               }
    };

    return $.ajax({
           url: url,
           method: "POST",
           data: JSON.stringify(queryPayload),
           headers: {
              "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
              "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
              "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose"
           }
     });
}
```

Usage

```
getListItems(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'Pages', '', '/Pages/Archive')
.then(function(data)
{
     var items = data.d.results;
     for(var i = 0; i < items.length;i++) {
         console.log(items[i].Title);
     }    
})
.fail(function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

Comment: WOW Thanks Lot , you saved me a lot of time , I tried the first option and it works like grand:) I also can get taxonomy single select value label , which is not possible to get it by _api/web/lists/getByTitle('list name')/items" ,  but surprisingly now I am not able to get multiple select Taxonomy fields , I get null value by this REST URL ,do you have any idea about it?

Comment: I have another question , I would need to filter as well , I used "_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(<serverrelativefolderurl>)/files?$expand=ListItemAllField$filter=ACT eq '23'  , the "ACT" is columns name which has returned under ListItemAllField , but I get Error message "Field or property \"ACT\" does not exist." , is there any way to filter this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a CAML query to specify a "filter"

In this CAML query you can use the field : **FileDirRef** and for value the serverRelativeURL of your folder.

This is an exemple of how to execute CAML query using REST API : [Using CAML with SharePoint REST API](https://chuvash.eu/2014/03/25/using-caml-with-sharepoint-rest-api/)

Answer (score 1):

**You can access files from specific folders using SharePoint 2013 REST API.**

END Point :

```
http://<site url>/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('/<folder name>')/files
```

This URL will return only files located under (one level beneath only) the specified folder.

References :

1. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841.aspx
2. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292553.aspx
3. [SharePoint REST API getFolderByServerRelativeUrl Returns Nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31662643/sharepoint-rest-api-getfolderbyserverrelativeurl-returns-nothing)